# How to make a send yourself a copy check box

Tags: php, html, checkbox, contact-form

I need a check box that can send yourself a copy. For example, they've filled out the contact form and want a copy sent to their self, they check the box and it will email it to me and still email it to them. Here's my PHP:

```
 //If the form is submitted
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
      $hasError = true;
    } else {
      $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
    }

    //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
      $hasError = true;
    } else {
      $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }

    //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['weburl']) == '') {
      $site = trim($_POST['weburl']);
    }

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
      $hasError = true;
    } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
      $hasError = true;
    } else {
      $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    //Check to make sure comments were entered
    if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
      $hasError = true;
    } else {
      if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
      } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
      }
    }

    //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!isset($hasError)) {
      $emailTo = 'myemail@domain.com'; // Put your own email address here
      $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nSite:  \n\nComments:\n $comments";
      $headers = 'From: BTSyncrets Contact <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

      mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
      $emailSent = true;
    } 
  }
```

Here's my contact form code:

```
<div id="contact" class="offset4 login">
        <form style="margin-top: 5% !important;" method="post" action="index.php" id="contactform">
          <fieldset class="well">
            <br>

            <div class="clearfix">
              <label for="name">
                Your Name<span class="help-required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="boxblack" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="span6 required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="clearfix">
              <label for="email">
                Your Email<span class="help-required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="boxblack" name="email" id="email" value="" class="span6 required email" role="input" aria-required="true" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
              <label for="weburl">
                Your Website
              </label>
              <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="boxblack" name="weburl" id="weburl" value="" class="span6 required url" role="input" aria-required="true" />
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="clearfix">
              <label for="subject">
                Subject<span class="help-required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="input">
                <select name="subject" id="boxblack" id="subject" class="span6 required" role="select" aria-required="true">
                  <option></option>
                  <option>One</option>
                  <option>Two</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
              <label for="message">Message<span class="help-required">*</span></label>
              <div class="input">
                <textarea rows="8" id="boxblack" style="resize: none;" name="message" id="message" class="span6 required" role="textbox" aria-required="true"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="copy" value="1" /> Send Yourself a copy
            </label>


            <div class="actions">
              <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-inverse" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
              <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" class="btn btn-danger" title="Remove all the data from the form." />
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: Long time no see, `eregi`

Comment: or a BCC or CC to the headers

Comment: @OneTrickPony I'm getting an error saying that theres a line where the `if isset($_POST['copy'])` is, @Dagon how would I do that? I'm sorry I'm new to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `Add this` comment below.

```
//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
  $emailTo = 'myemail@domain.com'; // Put your own email address here
  $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nSite:  \n\nComments:\n $comments";
  $headers = 'From: BTSyncrets Contact <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

// Add this
  if (isset($_POST['copy'])) {
      $headers .= "\nBcc: myemailaddress@example.com";
  }

  mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
  $emailSent = true;
}
```

Comment: It's saying that I'm getting an error on line 162 but that's the closing HTML tag

Comment: What's the error? If you remove my patch does the error go away?

Comment: Yes it does, here's the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/nickfost/public_html/sites/btsyncrets/pages/contact/index.php on line 162` the page is white and thats the only thing on it

Comment: That error is usually symptomatic of a missing closing brace. If you're sure that you've copied my patch accurately, and you're still getting the error I'll have to set this up on my development server and double check it there. This will take a while - I haven't had breakfast yet!